# Wald–Wolfowitz Runs Test

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

Does Mathematica 8 implement [Wald–Wolfowitz runs test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test) for randomness? I can't find it in the documentation. I would like to test some fit residuals.

Comment: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/Feb/msg00047.html any use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not built into the system as far as I can tell. However, it's a really good example of how to construct a fairly sophisticated function using just a few lines of code. I've taken the definition directly from the Wikipedia page, and applied it to `Sign[data]` on the assumption that if you are testing residuals from a regression, you are interested in runs of positive and negative values.

```
runstest[x:{__?NumericQ}] := 
 Module[{n = Length[x], res = Sign[x], n1, n2, runs, mu, sig2, y},
  {n1, n2} = Last /@ Tally[res];
  runs = Split[res];
  mu = 2 n1 n2/n + 1;
  sig2 = (mu - 1) (mu - 2)/(n - 1);
  NProbability[y <= Length[runs], 
    y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[N@mu, N@sig2]] ]
```

Some notable things about this code:

1. The pattern `{__?NumericQ}`. This ensures that the function only works on vectors of numeric data.
2. The use of local variables via `Module`, some of which can be set initially in the first argument of `Module`, while others can wait till later, perhaps because they depend on other local variables.
3. The use of `Tally` and `Split`, built-in functions that automatically divide lists into sublists of like elements.
4. The use of `NProbability` to work out the one-tailed test. Alternatively the last line could be something like `N@CDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sig2], Length[runs]]`: it gives the same answer except where the *p*-value is so tiny that numerical error creeps in (but seriously, who cares if it's $10^{-16}$ or $10^{-20}$?). It's possible that you want to express the test a different way, in which case that line is easy to modify.

Here is some test data that should definitely be rejected as random because of strong serial correlation:

```
testdata1 = 
  FoldList[0.98 #1 + #2 &, RandomReal[], 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], 100]];
```

And here is some data that should probably pass the test.

```
testdata2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], 100];
```

Sure enough:

```
runstest[testdata1]

(* -7.90479*10^-14 *)

runstest[testdata2]

(* 0.451757 *)
```

Comment: There is the nice identity `NProbability[y <= Length[runs], y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[N@mu, N@sig2]] == 1 - NProbability[y > Length[runs], y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[N@mu, N@sig2]]` you could use to simplify the last line of your function; it is also much more numerically sound to avoid the subtraction of near-equal quantities whenever possible.

Comment: @Verbeia: Why do you reject the two testdata?
What is the expected value for an accettable random dataset?
Thanks!

Comment: @meriens you have twice now posted answers that are really comments.  I converted this one for you.  If you will participate just a little more you will soon have the [comment everywhere](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) privilege.